# App crashes when I set FirebaseAdapterUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

ChatActivity crashes when I received the message in Firebase adapter UI. When I set this to `simple_list_item_1` layout, it works fine, but when I set with two or more attributes, the app crashed on receiving the message.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ProfileAcrivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button log_out;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Button send;
    EditText messgae;
    ListView messagelist;
    FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>firebaseListAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_acrivity);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        log_out = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_out);
        send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        messgae= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mess_text);
        messagelist= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mess_list);

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
        }
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("group");

        log_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
            }
        });
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                messageSend();
            }
        });

        messageRecieved();


    }

    void logout() {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
    }

    void messageSend()
    {
        databaseReference.push().setValue(new Chat(messgae.getText().toString(),firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
        messgae.setText(" ");
    }
    void messageRecieved()
    {

        firebaseListAdapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(this,Chat.class,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,databaseReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Chat model, int position) {
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getMessage());
            }
        };
        messagelist.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is my Chat.java File

```
    public class Chat {
    String message;
    String name;
    //String time;

    public Chat(String message,String user)
    {
        this.message=message;
        this.name=user;
    }



    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
02-10 01:15:07.106 15809-15809/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.firebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: a52.puri.fbkunal.com.firebase, PID: 15809
                                                                           com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class a52.puri.fbkunal.com.firebase.Chat is missing a constructor with no arguments
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaG(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseListAdapter.java:127)
                                                                               at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getItem(FirebaseListAdapter.java:116)
                                                                               at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:146)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2306)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1627)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2162)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1998)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5652)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 01:15:11.770 15809-15850/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.firebase W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: If your app crashes, there will be a stack trace in your logcat. Please edit your question to include that stack trace.

Comment: i am included the stack trace

Comment: Reading that stack trace really would help save you time from coming to StackOverflow... `Chat is missing a constructor with no arguments`

Answer (score 3):

Make a constructor of type

```
Chat(){}
```

Inside your chat class.

Firebase needs this default constructor. Since you have a parameterized one, you need to explicitly declare the constructor with no arguments as the compiler won't do that for you anymore.

Comment: Thanks bro ..that Works

Comment: Glad to help... Accept the answer if it did :)